# mdraid in weird state after failed rebuild

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, raid5, md

So my NAS (mdraid level5) mainboard died and I built a new system - there I reassembled the raid and the rebuild started:

```
md0 : active raid5 sde4[3] sdc4[0] sdd4[2] sdb4[4]
  8634123072 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [U_UU]
  [>....................]  recovery =  4.2% (121889248/2878041024) finish=394.4min speed=116448K/sec
```

After some hours I returned and the rebuild had failed with some IO errors.
I restarted the system tried reassembling again - but all drives were now spare:

```
root@el-kisto:~# mdadm --assemble  /dev/md0 /dev/sd[b-e]4 --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdb4 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdc4 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdd4 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sde4 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: added /dev/sdc4 to /dev/md0 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 1 of /dev/md0
mdadm: added /dev/sde4 to /dev/md0 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdb4 to /dev/md0 as 5
mdadm: added /dev/sdd4 to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.

root@el-kisto:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sdb4[5](S) sdc4[0](S) sdd4[2](S) sde4[3](S)
      11512164096 blocks
```

Examining with mdadm yields the following:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcde]4 | egrep 'dev|Update|Role|State|Chunk Size|Events'
/dev/sdb4:
    Update Time : Mon Aug 28 02:05:59 2023
          State : clean
         Events : 2045534
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     5       8       20        5      spare   /dev/sdb4
   2     2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
   3     3       8       68        3      active sync   /dev/sde4
   4     4       8       36        4      faulty   /dev/sdc4
/dev/sdc4:
    Update Time : Mon Aug 28 01:54:48 2023
          State : clean
         Events : 2045530
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       36        0      active sync   /dev/sdc4
   0     0       8       36        0      active sync   /dev/sdc4
   2     2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
   3     3       8       68        3      active sync   /dev/sde4
   4     4       8       20        4      spare   /dev/sdb4
/dev/sdd4:
    Update Time : Mon Aug 28 02:05:59 2023
          State : clean
         Events : 2045534
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
   2     2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
   3     3       8       68        3      active sync   /dev/sde4
   4     4       8       36        4      faulty   /dev/sdc4
/dev/sde4:
    Update Time : Mon Aug 28 02:05:59 2023
          State : clean
         Events : 2045534
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8       68        3      active sync   /dev/sde4
   2     2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
   3     3       8       68        3      active sync   /dev/sde4
   4     4       8       36        4      faulty   /dev/sdc4
```

This doesn't look too bad, the event counter is the same for 3/4 disks and the one behind is the one that was rebuilt anyway. But somehow md does seem to think that there should be 5 devices now?
The culprit seems to be sdb4, which self-identifies as spare and #5, when it should be active and #4 ?
--force during assembly does not help.
how do I conveince md to take in sd[bde]4 as a degraded 4-disk arry?